# Splash Screen flickers in Android with React Native Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, splash-screen, mobile-development

I'm developing a react native app with expo and native code (app client).

[VIDEO](https://res.cloudinary.com/dynsmaeo3/video/upload/v1701980338/SPOTLIVE-STATIC/iel4az9bgm623vmmmnfb.mp4)

Ever since I implemented the splashecreen with expo's default settings (in the app.json file) this has been giving problems. As you can see from the [video](https://res.cloudinary.com/dynsmaeo3/video/upload/v1701980338/SPOTLIVE-STATIC/iel4az9bgm623vmmmnfb.mp4), it changes height and flashes annoyingly. I tried to solve it natively by adding these lines in the manifest but nothing.

```
  <style name="Theme.App.SplashScreen" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#090909</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#090909</item>
  </style>
```

Some advice?

Comment: I think that shift you're seeing is the app going into full screen mode.

Comment: @Ars_Codicis  How do I prevent this?